# Append and Load from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-load, jquery-append

I'm pretty new to javascript and jQuery in general and I've been working on this script for about 3 days now. I searched around for a solution to this but wasn't able to find it yet. I guess my search skills suck.

So, I'm trying to load an element by from multiple pages and append them to an existing DIV. For example, I have a page called test.php which has `<div id="container">` in it. I also have multiple other pages called:

- pizzas.php
- pies.php
- apples.php
- oranges.php
- mangos.php
- etc

These are the pages that I'll be pulling data from to load into test.php. Each of the listed pages has `<div id="about">` somewhere in it.

Users will send me a string of pages that they'd like to load from through a text field they fill out. I take that and split it. Using that array, I'd like to create some DIV's for each string in that array. So this is where I'm at so far, assuming a user who has requested info from pizzas, pies, and apples:

```
<script>
var str = "pizzas,pies,apples";
var test = str.split(",");

$.each(test, function(i,v){
  $('#container').append('<div id="' + v + '"></div>');
});

</script>
```

Which yields:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="pizzas"></div>
  <div id="pies"></div>
  <div id="apples"></div>
</div>
```

After creating the new DIV's, I want to load `#about` from each page into its corresponding DIV. I thought I could do it by adding this to the each loop, but it doesn't work:

```
$( '"#' + v + '"' ).load( "index.php?x=" + v + " #about" );
//like $("#pizzas").load('index.php?x=pizzas #about');
```

And that's where I get stuck. Anyway, I'd greatly appreciate any help I could get on this.

Comment: `<div id="#about">` the `#` is syntax falsy

Comment: Woops. Yeah, I typed that in wrong. Thanks for catching it. :)

Comment: its probably not working because you are adding quotes to your selector `$( '"#' + v + '"' )` should be: `$( '#' + v )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can just use something like this after you've created the divs:

```
$("#container > div").each(function() {
    $(this).load("index.php?x=" + this.id + " #about");
});
```

Or, just do in in one shot like this:

```
var str = "pizzas,pies,apples";
var test = str.split(",");

var container = $('#container');
$.each(test, function(i,v){
    $("<div></div>", {id: v}).appendTo(container)
        .load("index.php?x=" + v + " #about");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a lot more elegant and simple than what I thought up, haha.